# Add link to Github repo for "Free Programming EBooks" question

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, post-notices

The post https://stackoverflow.com/q/194812 is mentioned [here](http://lifehacker.com/grab-over-500-free-programming-books-from-github-1447805132), because it was converted into a [**collaborative GitHub repository**](https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books):

[image]

By the way, seems the perfect venue for this kind of *Let's make a list of things* Questions. The numbers of the repo are amazing:

[image]

I'd like to suggest that a link to the GitHub project to be put in place in the historical locked post, as a comment or in the body of the post.

Comment: Does that mean that we can ***finally*** delete that damn question?

Comment: Or delete all the answers and add a new and only one: [*`This is how programmers make collaborative lists`*](https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books).

Comment: No, just delete it. It has been used in the past and will be used as evidence that such questions should be allowed and that it's a good thing to have these questions and that we are stupid idiots for not allowing new ones and so on...can we now just delete it? Someone who uses a search machine will find the GitHub repo, so everyone will be fine.

Comment: So, I guess this very post is now a good evidence to burninate that one. Kein problem!

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby: This has came up time and time again and the result was to keep the post.

Comment: @0A0D: The argument always was "this list is too useful to delete it", but now it is *actively* maintained somewhere else...so we can finally delete this question before it starts to rot into a stinking pile.

Comment: The problem with deleting it is that now we've got multiple large sites on the internet that link to it.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby: The github site is external to SO and has little to do with SO. Anyone can fork a question and answer onto github from SO, but that doesn't mean we should start deleting questions and answers.

Comment: I don't get why deleting the contents a question that drives traffic to the site is a good thing.  "It provides bad evidence for new bad questions" seems fairly flimsy, since the community clearly rejects that evidence when mod'ing new questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've added a notice to the answer that has this list.

I'm on the fence on deleting the question because multiple large sites now point to this Stack Overflow question, in addition to the countless links this question already has.

I want to delete it (in the same way I really want to delete the Definitive C++ book guide).  I can see keeping the question, deleting all the answers, deleting the text out of the top answer and replacing that text with the github link. That way we don't break the internet.

Update:

I've deleted all the answers, except the top one (they were superfluous anyway since all their information was in the master link).

I'd like to delete it as well, but the only reason I'm hesitant to is that it then breaks the Q&A nature of our questions. Sigh. I opened it in an incognito window and it definitely looks cleaner than before.

Comment: I'm all for deleting the answers and maybe even rewrite the question to contain a text with the link. That way it can at least not be used as evidence anymore. Like a text-only redirect.

Comment: @TimeTravelingBobby: "What do you mean my link-only answer is bad? Look at that one over there!!!!!!1!"

Comment: @Wooble: Ha! I meant editing the question text! ... "If it is discouraged, why does it have more then 2.4k upvotes?!" \*shudders\*