# Ground rules for creating GitHub repos from SE content?

Tags: discussion, etiquette, licensing

What are the ground rules applicable to forking over community wiki content from StackExchange to GitHub?

I surmise that License CC-by-SA 3.0 Unported should be kept at all times. Need more information on etiquette and content constraints:

- How should the repo link back to the underlying post (top or bottom section of `README.md`, or somewhere else)?
- Should there be a link to the repo in the underlying post?
- If the repo is unmaintained, should the link be deleted?
- Should the underlying post be deleted once forked over to GitHub? (probably not but need positive reassurance on this)

References:

- https://github.com/Hunter-Github/awesome-space-books (I based it on [Resources and references on the topic of space exploration](https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/q/249/168))
- https://github.com/dhilipsiva/webapp-checklist (forked off [What technical details should a programmer of a web application consider before making the site public?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46716/what-technical-details-should-a-programmer-of-a-web-application-consider-before))
- https://github.com/vhf/free-programming-books (based on the (in)famous https://stackoverflow.com/q/194812 , discussed in [Add link to Github repo for "Free Programming EBooks" question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202681/add-link-to-github-repo-for-free-programming-ebooks-question))